# Adding suffix to multiple files

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I am a novice in powershell and command prompt. I have a bunch of files in a folder and need to add a suffix to each individual file name.

Is there a code for powershell or command prompt that could do that? 
Also would it be possible for the code to automatically have the suffix be whatever the folder name is that all the files are in?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and with what results?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple to do with Move-Item using a scriptblock parameter to compute the destination path name.

```
dir *.txt | Move-Item -Destination {$_.BaseName +'.' + ($pwd | split-path -leaf)}
```